# (minimum or maximum) sum of codomain in Excel 2019

Tags: excel, excel-formula

### **initial situation:**

I would like to add several codomains in Excel 2019. For this I need the minimum sum and the maximum sum of the codomain and ideally also the calculated codomain. That is:

#image

The green cells (`B6`, `B7`, `B8`) show the expected result but hard coded.

[image]

## **question:**

**Are there in-build functions in Excel for this and what is the cleanest way to solve this requirement, i.e. not work with `substrings` if possible.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using SUMPRODCUT:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--LEFT(B1:B4,FIND("-",B1:B4)-1))&"-"&SUMPRODUCT(--MID(B1:B4,FIND("-",B1:B4)+1,5))
```

The first SUMPRODUCT does the Min Sum and the second the Max.

[image]

With Office 365:

```
=SUM(--TEXTBEFORE(B1:B4,"-"))&"-"&SUM(--TEXTAFTER(B1:B4,"-"))
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution. How can I preemptively deal with user input errors? I.e. if there is no codomains in a cell, but only a number?

Comment: That is out of scope for this question.  Please try to fix on your own and if not able, ask a NEW question.  DO NOT edit this question to include the new criteria as it will make my answer open for down votes.

Comment: okay all right, I have created a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76957098/sum-of-codomain-in-excel-2019-with-conditions)