# sum of codomain in Excel 2019 with conditions

Tags: excel, excel-formula

### **initial situation:**

Following on from my [first question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76949038/minimum-or-maximum-sum-of-codomain-in-excel-2019),

> *I would like to add several codomains in Excel 2019. For this I need the minimum sum and the maximum sum of the codomain and ideally also the calculated codomain.*

I would now like to link the codomain calculation to a condition (*if $A="X"*) and prevent errors (*e.g. if, as in B4, there is only a single digit instead of expected acodomain => then this should be the "codomain" between the specified number and itself => see C4*).

The green cell (`B8`) show the expected result but hard coded.

[image]

## **question:**

**How can I include these two conditions in the existing formula?**

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--LEFT(B2:B6,FIND("-",B2:B6)-1))&"-"&SUMPRODUCT(--MID(B2:B6,FIND("-",B2:B6)+1,LEN(B2:B6)-FIND("-",B2:B6)))
```

### My current status:

Requirements:

1. condition in column A
2. act preventively in case of missing `-` sign

#### RE1)

Formulate the condition:

```
(A2:A6="X")*1
```

*The result can only be TRUE (=1) or FALSE (=0). The multiplication "*1" is necessary so that the result TRUE or FALSE is also correctly recognized as 0 or 1 in the matrix.*

=> adapted formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A2:A6="X")*1;--LEFT(B2:B6,FIND("-",B2:B6)-1))&"-"&SUMPRODUCT((A2:A6="X")*1;--MID(B2:B6,FIND("-",B2:B6)+1,LEN(B2:B6)-FIND("-",B2:B6)))
```

This also works for me. Only I do not have a workable approach for requirement 2 (**RE2**).

The first idea was `(NOT(ISERROR(FIND("-";B2:B6)`, but unfortunately this approach has not been very successful so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A2:A6="X")*(LEFT(B2:B6,FIND("-",B2:B6&"-")-1)))&"-"&SUMPRODUCT((A2:A6="X")*(MID(B2:B6,IFERROR(FIND("-",B2:B6),0)+1,10)))
```

With the addition of the IFERROR, this will probably require the use of Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. It works as expected.

Unfortunately, I forgot one more edge case, so I created a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77009861/sum-of-codomain-in-excel-2019-with-conditions-and-preventive-troubleshooting-by) again, since I learned not to add to the existing one.

Answer (score 0):

Using <kbd>REPLACE( )</kbd> function.

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>B8</kbd>

```
=SUMPRODUCT(REPLACE(B2:B6,FIND("-",B2:B6&"-"),99,)*(A2:A6="X"))&"-"&
 SUMPRODUCT((A2:A6="X")*REPLACE(B2:B6,1,IFERROR(FIND("-",B2:B6),0),))
```

---

Depending on ones excel version, one need to hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> while exiting the edit mode.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It works. Unfortunately, I can only mark one correct answer, otherwise I would have liked to mark yours as the correct solution as well.

Comment: @nerdyitguy nevermind, you have accepted the one it has to be, because Scott Craner's sir solution is more apt one.