# Sum of codomain in Excel 2019 with conditions and preventive troubleshooting by `SUMPRODUCT`

Tags: excel, excel-formula

### **initial situation:**

Following on from my [second question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76957098/sum-of-codomain-in-excel-2019-with-conditions),

> *I would like to add several codomains in Excel 2019. For this I need the minimum sum and the maximum sum of the codomain and ideally also the calculated codomain. Link the codomain calculation to a condition (*if $A="X"*) and prevent errors (*e.g. if, as in B4, there is only a single digit instead of expected codomain => then this should be the "codomain" between the specified number and itself => see C4*).*

I would like to preventively avoid errors if column B contains an empty cell [orange cells] (!= 0 but ""), because the `SUMPRODUCT` cannot handle this.

[image]

## **question:**

**How can I include this error prevention in the existing formula?**

### current status:

So far, I have used the suggested solutions below from question two, but I have not been able to adapt them to the required requirement.

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A2:A6="X")*(LEFT(B2:B6,FIND("-",B2:B6&"-")-1))) &"-"& 
 SUMPRODUCT((A2:A6="X")*(MID(B2:B6,IFERROR(FIND("-",B2:B6),0)+1,10)))
```

*With the IFERROR()-formula I have already tried many things, but always without success unfortunately.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using <kbd>IFERROR( )</kbd>

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>B8</kbd>

```
=SUMPRODUCT(IFERROR((A2:A6="X")*(LEFT(B2:B6,FIND("-",B2:B6&"-")-1)),0)) &"-"&
 SUMPRODUCT(IFERROR((A2:A6="X")*(MID(B2:B6,IFERROR(FIND("-",B2:B6),0)+1,10)),0))
```

---

Caveat: You may need to hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> while exiting the edit mode.